# How is this java code is deleting an item from a list without using .remove()?

Tags: java, arrays, queue

I'm reading an algorithms textbook and I came across this line from a code example:
 `long temp = queArray[front++];`
I understand what the front++ is doing and what item it is accessing, but this seems to be also deleting the item from the array. I don't understand how it is doing that.

In case I missed something, here is the rest of the method:

```
public long remove()  {       // take item from front of queue
    long temp = queArray[front++]; // get value and incr front
    if(front == maxSize)           // deal with wraparound
        front = 0;
    nItems--;                      // one less item
    return temp;
}
```

Additionally, here is the rest of the class:

```
 class Queue
   {
   private int maxSize;
   private long[] queArray;
   private int front;
   private int rear;
   private int nItems;

   public Queue(int s)          // constructor
      {
      maxSize = s;
      queArray = new long[maxSize];
      front = 0;
      rear = -1;
      nItems = 0;
      }

   public void insert(long j)   // put item at rear of queue
      {
      if(rear == maxSize-1)         // deal with wraparound
         rear = -1;
      queArray[++rear] = j;         // increment rear and insert
      nItems++;                     // one more item
      }

   public long remove()         // take item from front of queue
      {
      long temp = queArray[front++]; // get value and incr front
      if(front == maxSize)           // deal with wraparound
         front = 0;
      nItems--;                      // one less item
      return temp;
      }

   public long peekFront()      // peek at front of queue
      {
      return queArray[front];
      }

   public boolean isEmpty()    // true if queue is empty
      {
      return (nItems==0);
      }

   public boolean isFull()     // true if queue is full
      {
      return (nItems==maxSize);
      }

   public int size()           // number of items in queue
      {
      return nItems;
      }

   }  // end class Queue
```

Comment: We have no idea which list you're talking about, since you only posted a tiny amount of code. There is an array used in this code, and thde code only reads from that array. That's all we can say.

Comment: Sorry I didn't post enough. I'll add the rest of the class to my original post.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure this is just setting the "front" to be the next element of the array, so that it will be accessed next. This isn't deleting anything, just letting you get the next item, or wrapping back around to the front if you're at the end

Comment: It looks like this code uses a fixed-size ring buffer for a queue. It "removes" an element by moving the "front" pointer one item up, and decreases the "items in queue" counter - there is no need to move around elements in the array that is used to store the data for the queue.